# What process is a device driver loaded into on Windows?

Tags: windows, driver, internals

When a device is connected to a computer running Windows, the PnP Manager handles loading the device driver for it. Just curious, what process is a device driver (.sys file) loaded into?

Comment: drivers always is loaded in context of system process. [*`DriverEntry` routines are called in the context of a system thread at `IRQL = PASSIVE_LEVEL`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/writing-a-driverentry-routine)

Comment: Thanks. Is that the same for user mode drivers?

Comment: no, user mode drivers (if you mean *UMDF*) loaded (as dll) and executed in context of *WUDFHost.exe*

Comment: Thank you. Can you post a link so I can research more widely?